# Can the eigenvalues of a matrix always be expressed in terms of the traces of its powers?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my research, I came across a cute identity involving the eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2$ Hermitian matrix $M$.  These two eigenvalues can be expressed as follows:
$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{tr } M \pm \sqrt{ 2 \text{tr}\left( M^2 \right) - \left(\text{tr } M \right)^2} \right]
$$
The way I proved this was simply to write out $M$ in terms of its components and then solve the eigenvalue problem.  This is fine as far as it goes, but I'm assuming that this result is already known, and I'm curious about what else is known about it.  Specifically:

- Is there a nicer way to prove this identity without doing things in terms of the matrix components?  The identity itself is nice & component-free, so I feel like there should be some component-free way of proving it.
- Are there any generalizations of this identity to larger matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trace of $M^n$ is $p_n = \sum_{\xi_i\in E}\xi_i^n$ where $E$ is the multiset of eigenvalues of $M$. The power sums are a base of the ring of the symmetric functions as well as the elementary symmetric functions. As a matter of fact, we may switch from one base to the other through [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities). But the elementary symmetric functions of the eigenvalues give the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial by Viète's formulas. So if $M$ is a $m\times m$ matrix and we know $\text{Tr}(M),\ldots,\text{Tr}(M^m)$, we also know the eigenvalues of $M$. A numerical algorithm for the eigenvalue determination through the previous facts is sometimes known as *circle method*: as a reference, have a look at page 175 of [these notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: You beat me to it. You type fast :-) +1, of course. I also want to comment that the when $m\ge5$ we don't have a formula for the individual eigenvalues in terms of traces, radicals and other algebraic operations.